# 2-loop correction to the Beta function in Fradkin's OPE-based RG

Tags: field-theory, renormalization, research-level, regularization

In chapter 4.5 of Fradkin's book "Field Theories for Condensed Matter Physics" (page 81 in my version) he claims that "it is straightforward to see that this [the perturbative calculation of the beta function]  repeats to all orders (cf. cubic terms and higher
in Eq. (4.53))". Now I would definitely agree that the calculation he does up to 1-loop order (== quadratic terms) is "straightforward" -- but the more I play around with his RG scheme, the more confused I get regarding how to address the next order (2-loop or cubic terms).

TL;DR: How does one calculate the 2-loop term in principal (maybe for some simple example)?

To show what I did let me first summarize how Fradkin sets up the RG:
For simplicity I will assume that we only have a single perturbation operator $$S=S_0 + \frac{g}{a^{D-\Delta}} \int \mathcal{O}(x_1)\, \text{d}^Dx_1$$
where $S_0$ is some "fixed point action" (think something like $\int (\nabla\phi)^2$), $a$ is a short-distance cut-off acting as the UV-regulator and $\Delta$ is the scaling dimension of $\mathcal{O}$.
Now expanding the partition function gives
$$\frac{Z}{Z_0} = 1 + \frac{g}{a^{D-\Delta}} \int \langle\mathcal{O}(x_1)\rangle\, \text{d}^Dx + \frac{1}{2!} \left(\frac{g}{a^{D-\Delta}} \right)^2 \int_{|x_1-x_2|>a} \langle\mathcal{O}(x_1)\mathcal{O}(x_2)\rangle\, \text{d}^Dx_1\, \text{d}^Dx_2 + O(g^3)$$
where the expectation values are with respect to $S_0$ and we avoid singularities by limiting the integral to values $|x_1-x_2|>a$.
The idea of the RG is now to see how the coupling $g$ changes when we increase $a$ a bit via $a\rightarrow a'=a \text{e}^{\text{d}l} = a + a \text{d}l$.
Leading order (or tree level) gives $g'=g + (D-\Delta) g\text{d}l$ and for the 1-loop correction one simply rewrites the integral ($S_D$ is the area of the $D$-dimensional hypersphere)
$$\int_{|x_1-x_2|>a} = \int_{|x_1-x_2|>a} + \int_{a'>|x_1-x_2|>a}$$
and uses the OPE $\mathcal{O}(x)\mathcal{O}(x+\epsilon) \sim \frac{C}{\epsilon^\Delta} \mathcal{O}(x)$ to get
$$\int_{a'>|x_1-x_2|>a}\langle\mathcal{O}(x_1)\mathcal{O}(x_2)\rangle\, \text{d}^Dx_1\, \text{d}^Dx_2 = S_Da^D \text{d}l \frac{C}{a^\Delta} \int \langle\mathcal{O}(x_1)\rangle\, \text{d}^Dx_1$$
and therefore $g'=g + (D-\Delta) g\text{d}l + \frac{S_DC}{2!}g^2$ which can then be converted into the differental equation
$$\frac{\text{d}g}{\text{d}l} = (D-\Delta) g + \frac{S_DC}{2} g^2.$$
So far so good, but somehow the next order fails to actually generate a new contribution.
The third order term is
$$\frac{1}{3!}\left(\frac{g}{a^{D-\Delta}} \right)^3 \int_{x_{12}>a, x_{13}>a, x_{23}>a} \langle\mathcal{O}(x_1)\mathcal{O}(x_2)\mathcal{O}(x_3)\rangle$$
and now we need to modify the boundaries again.
Here I find that the difference between the integral with $a$ and $a'$ is (skipping a bunch of steps)
$$\int_{x_{12}, x_{13}, x_{23}>a} - \int_{x_{12}, x_{13}, x_{23}>a'}  = 3S_DC a^{D-\Delta}\text{d}l \int_{x_{12}>a} \langle\mathcal{O}(x_1)\mathcal{O}(x_2)\rangle - 3(S_DC a^{D-\Delta})^2 \text{d}l^2 \int \langle\mathcal{O}(x_1)\rangle.$$
Now the $\text{d}l$-term is really just the $\frac{S_DC}{2}g^2$-term in disguise (skipping some more steps...) and the only new term could be the $\text{d}l^2$-thing -- but that should just vanish in the construction of the ODE.
Assuming I have not messed up badly this actually holds to arbitrary order (at least for a single operator)

So: What went wrong? Is the 2-loop order just not something we can get out of this particular RG or did I misunderstand the procedure?

(this is long enough as it is so I leave out some details of the calculation for now -- I can provide them if someone is interested)